# Switching Unity layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can someone help me solve this problem, I am beginner and I have no idea why this doesn't work.

```
void SwitchColor(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        if(isWhite){
            isWhite = false;
            gameObject.layer = 10;
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
        }
        if(!isWhite){
            isWhite = true;
            gameObject.layer = 11;
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to switch two layers on game object. I just throwed this in Update() and it just don't do anything. When I used print() there, it worked, but not the rest.

Comment: Please specify what is "not work" and tell us what you expect this code to do and what it does instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
// Set true for this scenario
isWhite = true;

if(isWhite) // isWhite is true,  this condition is valid
{
    // Then isWhite set to false
    isWhite = false;
    gameObject.layer = 10;
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
}
if(!isWhite) // isWhite is false, then this condition is valid
{
    isWhite = true; // Then isWhite set to true
    gameObject.layer = 11;
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
}
```

When `iSwhite` is true, the two block is executed. You need to use [if/else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) like :

```cs
if(isWhite)
{
    isWhite = false;
    gameObject.layer = 10;
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
}
else
{
    isWhite = true;
    gameObject.layer = 11;
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
}
```